# Renaming JSON files based on their contents

Tags: json, linux, bash, unix, scripting

I have loads of geographical json files with `date_geohash.json` name format and I have to convert them to `date_latitude-longotude.json` format. For example I need to convert `2017-03-28_u13hhyn.json` to `2017-03-28_N52.76-E1.62.json`.
 
I'm trying to write a bash script to rename these json files using 'rename' and 'jq' (json query) utilities. Using jq I can extract latitude and longitude from the json files.

```
jq '"\(.latitude)-\(.longitude).json"' 2017-03-28_u13hhyn.json
```

gives me

```
“52.768471-1.623297.json"
```

However, I don't know how to truncate the latitude and longitude digits and rename the json files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to extract the latitude and longitude into variables, then manipulate into the filename format you want with printf. Then just rename the file. Here's a basic example:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare    directory="/some/directory/path"
declare    pattern="*_*.json"

cd ${directory}
for file in ${pattern}; do
  prefix=${file%%_*}    # Remove first underscore and everything following.
  latitude=$(jq '.latitude' ${file})
  longitude=$(jq '.longitude' ${file})
  new_name=$(printf "%s_N%.2f-E%.2f.json" ${prefix} ${latitude} ${longitude})
  mv ${file} ${new_name}
done;
```

Note 1: printf does not truncate the numbers, it rounds them, which is going to give more accurate results.

Note 2: I have hard-coded 'N' and 'E' into the filename, on the assumption that latitude and longitude will be negative for S and W. If this is not the case, there is a little more work required, but the priciple stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Following Andrew's code, I concluded:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.json; do
  prefix=${file%%_*} 
  latitude=$(jq '.latitude' ${file})
  longitude=$(jq '.longitude' ${file})

  if (( $(echo "$longitude > 0" | bc -l) )); then
    new_name=$(printf "%s_N%.2f-E%.2f.json" ${prefix} ${latitude} ${longitude})
  else
    Longitude=${longitude#-}
    new_name=$(printf "%s_N%.2f-W%.2f.json" ${prefix} ${latitude} ${Longitude})
  fi

  mv ${file} ${new_name}
done;
```

I'm wondering how can I use one printf instead of two?

Comment: Make a variable `EW="E"`. Do your `if` statement and if the longitude is negative, set `EW="W"` and remove the minus sign. After the `fi` do one `printf` but use `%s` where you had `E` or `W` and add `$EW` into the list of parameters you pass to `printf`.

Comment: Prefer `mv "${file}"  "${new_name}"` in case your filenames contain spaces.

Comment: The final code works correctly but it is awfully slow! I think it is due to jq. Can we make the script faster?

Comment: If your JSON file is large, you could maybe make it stop searching after it finds the first match https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1188

Comment: Or you could get lat and lon with a single `jq` invocation `read lat lon < <(jq '"\(.latitude) \(.longitude)"' file.json)`

Comment: Or search on Stack Overflow for `[gnu-parallel]` and get things done many times faster.

Comment: Thank Mark. There is only one latitude and one longitude in each json files. So I think stop searching after first match doesn’t help.